# Adding Mulitiple Lines on a TGraphError Graph (Root)

Tags: c++, root-framework

Suppose I have following TGraphError graph:

```
double ex_1[] = {0.4, 0.55, 0.73, 0.79, 0.89, 0.97};  
double ey_1[] = {0.275497,0.577353,1.12619,1.61994,1.44495,2.68186}; 
TGraphErrors* ge = new TGraphErrors(6, X_1, Y_1, ex_1, ey_1);
ge->Draw("AC*");
ge->GetXaxis()->SetLimits(-10. , 140);
dirOne->Append(ge);
```

How do I add a simple line on this graph say just x=0?

Comment: Could you give *two* points for the line you want drawn? Also, your example as is is incomplete since `X_1` and `Y_1` aren't defined here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that you want to draw a straight line on the graph, for reference rather than to add information.

This can be achieved using [`TLine`](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TLine.html) like so:

```
TLine line(x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1);
line.Draw();
```

which draws a line between points (x_0, y_0) and (x_1, y_1). The units are the units of the axis (e.g. in GeV). The attributes of the line can be changed, too (see [documentation](http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TLine.html)).

Comment: Can you explain why you think `line` needs to be allocated dynamically?

Comment: It depends on the context. That's up to the reader to decide.

Comment: I just disagree with the default approach to generally suggest potentially leaky code when working with ROOT like you did here.

Comment: To avoid arguing, I've changed it. But of course, it's impossible to avoid leaks when using ROOT in the first place...